# val() on iPhone iOS not returning textarea value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, iphone

The following val() call from a textarea is working fine on Firefox/Chrome on my desktop and laptop but on iPhone (safari) nothing is returned? I'm not sure what part of the iOS system stops this from working? Javascript is 'On' in settings.

```
$('textarea[name=username]').val()
```

Thanks

Comment: try the vanilla `value`, $('textarea[name=username]').value

Comment: @JonathandeM. jQuery objects don't have a `value` property

Comment: I think what @JonathandeM meant was `$('textarea[name=username]').get(0).value`

Comment: Tried both options with no success (no data returned). Is a val() call even possible in iOS with safari? Or it there another way to pull a value from a textarea for insertion into a javascript code?

Answer (score 2):

If anyone's looking for an answer to this, $().val() doesn't seem to work on iPhone, either as a getter or a setter. Instead, use $().attr('value') like this:

**Getter**

```
$('textarea[name=username]').attr('value');
```

**Setter**

```
$('textarea[name=username]').attr('value', 'elonmusk');
```